# load a previously removed module

Tags: nvidia, kernel-modules, opensuse, modprobe, nouveau

trying to install nvidia drivers and typed by chance: modprobe -r nouveau.
Is there a easy way to load again the module nouveau? both modprobe nouveau and modprobe -a nouveau do not work. I'm on Opensuse Leap 15.1

Cheers

Comment: Normally it's impossible to `rmmod nouveau` because it's responsible for KMS.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I just did a modprobe -r nouveau and now there is a blank screen where I can just move the mouse